# How to make Spring MVC return CSV as convenient as return JSON

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, jackson

I know Spring MVC could return a model in format of Json easily; however, I have tried quite different approaches to return a model in CSV format (via Jackson), but could not make it successfully.

What should I do?

I enclose my model code, controller code, and gradle.build as following:

Thanks a lot!

Model:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "staffName", "name" })
public class Greeter
{
    String name;
    String staffName[];

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String[] getStaffName()
    {
        return staffName;
    }

    public void setStaffName(String[] staffName)
    {
        this.staffName = staffName;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeter/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Greeter getGreeterInJSON() {

        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

        greeter.setName("default");
        greeter.setStaffName(new String[] { "ye", "lichi" });

        return greeter;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeter/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "text/csv")
    public @ResponseBody
    Greeter getGreeterInCSV(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

        greeter.setName("default");
        greeter.setStaffName(new String[] { "ye", "lichi" });

        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Greeter.class);

        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(schema.withLineSeparator("\n"));

        File greeterCSV = new File("greeterCSV.csv");

        try {
            writer.writeValue(greeterCSV, greeter);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return greeter;
    }
}
```

build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'

    compile ('org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.0.RELEASE')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M6")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:2.0.17")

    // compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13"
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.3.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
}
```

Edit:

---

Tomcat error:

HTTP Status 415 -

type Status report

message

description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: In what way does it not work correctly? Please provide any stack traces etc.

Answer (score 3):

You want not to consume but *produce* csv. The way you have it, the service expects the input to be provided in csv format, that's why it complains about 'request entity is in a format not supported'. Key is 'request' here - it expects some input in csv format.
Changing 'consume' to 'produces' should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

*I was looking for an answer to this question for a while and sadly found none, so I will give and example here.*

You need to add a CSV message converter. This `@Configuration` does this:

```
@Configuration
public class CsvConfiguration {

  @Bean
  JacksonToCsvHttpMessageConverter csvMessageConverter() {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    // configure mapper here
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return new JacksonToCsvHttpMessageConverter(mapper);
  }

}
```

And a converter itself:

Note that this simplified version does not support filters nor views. However, if you study the overridden method `writeInternal` you should be able to add these features, should you need them. Additionally, empty collections are not supported, but you can use an empty array, if you want to support empty series.

```
public class JacksonToCsvHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    protected JacksonToCsvHttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper, MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        if (object instanceof MappingJacksonValue) object = ((MappingJacksonValue) object).getValue();
        CsvMapper mapper = (CsvMapper) getObjectMapper();
        Class<?> klass = getType(object);
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(klass).withHeader();
        JsonEncoding encoding = getJsonEncoding(outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        try (CsvGenerator generator = mapper.getFactory().createGenerator(outputMessage.getBody(), encoding)) {
            ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().with(schema);
            writer.writeValue(generator, object);
        }
    }

    private Class<?> getType(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Collection) {
            Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) object;
            return c.iterator().next().getClass();
        }
        if (object.getClass().isArray()) return object.getClass().getComponentType();
        return object.getClass();
    }

}
```

This will enable all traditional controller methods to return CSV by the way of `Accept` header. `Accept: application/json` will yield JSON while `Accept: text/csv` will yield CSV. Of course all CsvMapper constraints will apply, so no nested objects etc.

```
@RestController
public class CsvController {

    @GetMapping("/records*")
    public CsvRecord[] getRecords() {
        return new CsvRecord[] { new CsvRecord(), new CsvRecord() };
    }

    @GetMapping("/record")
    public CsvRecord getRecord() {
        return new CsvRecord();
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
    public static class CsvRecord {
        public String name = "aa";
    }

}
```

Using this configuration will cause your app to return CSV for `Accept: */*` requests. This is rarely intended, so you can set the default content type to JSON by adding this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you are using GET so you are expecting something in response which is CSV so make sure to use produces = *"text/csv"* instead of consumes = "text/csv")
here :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeter/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "text/csv")
    public @ResponseBody
```

*we use consume when we send some*