# How to force the response of RestController to csv file

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-boot, swagger

I'm developing a Rest API, will be responsible to return a csv file as response.

This is my Api interface:

```
@Api(value = Constantes.REPORTS)
public interface ExtractFileApi {
  @RequestMapping(value = Constantes.REPORTS_URL, produces = "application/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getExtractFile() throws IOException;
}
```

And this is my interface implementation:

```
@RestController
public class ExtractFileApiController implements ExtractFileApi {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getExtractFile() throws IOException {
     ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("pdf-sample.csv");
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
     headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
     headers.add("Expires", "0");

     return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
}
```

For now, my API return a link to download the file, but I don't know how to force the response to be exactly a CSV file (file.csv).

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Hope this will help [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937842/how-to-make-spring-mvc-return-csv-as-convenient-as-return-json)

Comment: Can you state what language you are using in the title? This may help more qualified people to find an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change return type to **void** and then use following code at end

```
Path path = Paths.get(pdfFile.getPath()); 
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="
            + path.getFileName().toString().replace(" ", "_"));
    try {
        response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(path));
        response.setContentLength((int) Files.size(path));
        // Copy bytes from source to destination, closes both streams.
        FileCopyUtils.copy(Files.newInputStream(path),
                response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("fetching file failed", e);
        response.setStatus(500);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the production output MIME type to `text/csv` instead.